# Visual Studio 2017 linux can't compile if there's std::thread

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, visual-studio, compiler-errors

So I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2017 to create a Linux project.
I started out with an Empty Linux Project (as the project template), and so far everything is fine.

However, if I have

```
// Create a new thread for the connection to avoid clutter
std::thread newConnectionHandler(connectionHandler, iNewConnection);
newConnectionHandler.detach();
```

in my code, it won't compile. These are the errors that I get:

```
Error       E0020   identifier "__float128" is undefined
Error       In function `std::thread::thread<void(&)(int), int&>(void(&)(int), int&)':
Error       undefined reference to `pthread_create'
Error       ld returned 1 exit status
```

But as soon as I comment out the `std::thread` stuff, it compiles.

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

- C/C++ -> Additional Options -> Added `-pthread -lpthread` or just `-pthread`
- Linker -> Additional Options -> Added `-pthread -lpthread` or just `-pthread`
- Linker -> Library Dependencies -> Added `thread`
- Switching C++ Language standard between C++17 and C++11

And of course I've tried multiple variations of those changes, but I always get the same error.

And my includes are:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
```

EDIT:
Here's also the declaration of `connectionHandler`:

```
void connectionHandler(int iConnection)
```

And when passing `iNewConnection`, the datatype is an `int`.

Comment: @chris Alright, done.

Comment: You're fiddling with the linker, but your error is a compiler error. I think your header paths are wrong.

Comment: @Quentin, Perhaps I should have kept this half of my original comment, but the first error is Intellisense and the rest is the linker output, which means the compiler was fine with it.

Comment: @chris oh, alright. I don't have a better suggestion then :)

Comment: Check that you really have -pthread at the link stage, that the error you have.

Comment: That error usually shows up if you didn't add `-pthread` key in build stage. Maybe you just missed with settings

Comment: @Kordnak:  Is the `-pthread` last in the link command line after all of your object and library files?

Comment: @P.W that fixed my problem! I'm must have missed it somehow.

Comment: @Kordnak: Added that as an answer so that it can be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `-pthread` option to `Linker -> Command Line -> Additional Options`, it should also be the last in the link command line after all of your object and library files.

The order is important.

Comment: What do you mean "It is not enough"? I just tested with a new Linux Empty Project and adding `-pthread` to Linker's Additional Options was all I needed to do.

Comment: You said in your comment, that is what solved your issue, right? If it works irrespective of its position, please confirm and I will delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Putting -pthread in Linker -> Command Line -> Additional Options worked. Even if you are using using linux project then also you need to select the project properties in visual studio.

Thank You!!

Comment: Hi arimaknp, Welcome to StackOverflow. If another answer solved the problem for you, please consider up-voting that answer instead of adding a duplicate. This will help other users find answers quickly and with less confusion